# Get newly ordered data from Buefy table

Tags: vue.js, buefy

I have a Buefy table that has drag and drop implemented https://buefy.org/documentation/table#draggable-rows

My table only has one column. So after the user drags the rows around in the order they want them, I have them click a save button and on click i want to get the data from the table in the exact order the user put them in. I have a reference to my table:

```html
<b-table ref="reorder"
  v-sortable="sortableOptions"
  :data="data"
  :columns="columns"
  hoverable
  striped>
</b-table>
```

Here's the data:

```js
  columns: [
      {
        field: "item",
        label: "Name"
      }
    ],
  data:[{item:'row 1'},
        {item:'row 2'},
        {item:'row 3'}]
```

In my button click event, I have:

```js
refreshTable() {
  let tbl = this.$refs.reorder
},
```

I see a data object in this.$refs.reorder, but the order is in the same order as the data that was passed in when creating the table. I need to get the data from the table in the newly created order the user put it in after they're done dragging and dropping rows. How do i get the data in the newly sorted order? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to handle the drag events in order to manually reflect changes in your data.

For example, add a data property to hold the dragged row's index, eg

```js
data: () => ({
  columns: [{
    field: "item",
    label: "Name"
  }],
  data:[
    {item:'row 1'},
    {item:'row 2'},
    {item:'row 3'}
  ],
  draggingRowIndex: null //  add this
})
```

and methods to handle the `dragstart` and `drop` events

```js
methods: {
  dragstart (payload) {
    this.draggingRowIndex= payload.index
  },
  drop (payload) {
    // move the dragged row
    this.data.splice(payload.index, 0,
        ...this.data.splice(this.draggingRowIndex, 1))
  }
}
```

then bind these to the `<b-table>` events

```html
<b-table @dragstart="dragstart" @drop="drop"...>
```